# Name and interesting properties of this knot?

Tags: knot-theory

This image was used as logo by some astronomy institute.

I  am pretty much sure this is a mathematical object, some knot.

Is there any name for this knot, Does it have interesting properties.

[image]

Comment: As a practical knot, it's a form of the Carrick knot/Carrick bend. Hopefully that will at least narrow down some Google searches.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think it's this one: http://katlas.math.toronto.edu/wiki/8_18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the prime knot [$8_{18}$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrick_mat) (or perhaps [this](http://katlas.math.toronto.edu/wiki/8_18), from the comments above, is a better link).